# Assign a value to a "hidden" input webelement, in SeleniumBasic for Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I have to migrate a web automation program from IE controlled by Excel VBA to Chrome using selenium basic in Excel VBA.

The website itself is not public so I cannot share a link.

A page that displays a two week calendar defaults to start at today's date, to enter events on specific subsequent days.
I want to change the default date and have the website alter the dates displayed to start on that new date.
This involves changing the "Value" attribute of a hidden input webelement whose ID = "_ctl1_currentDate" which worked with IE using the native driver in VBA Excel.

I cannot get this to work with the Selenium Basic driver for Excel VBA for Chrome.

This is the html of the webelement:

```html
<input name="_ctl1:currentDate" type="hidden" id="_ctl1_currentDate" value="19/01/2022">
```

This is the Javascript associated with this webelement:

```js
<script language="javascript">

    /* une fonction permettant de se déplacer dans calendrier */
    function move(direction) {
        var date = document.getElementById("_ctl1_currentDate").value;
        var day;
        var month;
        var year;
        var t = new Date();
        var newDate;
        var newMonth;
        var newDay;

        if (date.charAt(2) == "/") {
            day = date.substring(0, 2);
            if (date.charAt(5) == "/") {
                month = date.substring(3, 5);
                year = date.substring(6, 10);
            } else {
                month = date.substring(3, 4);
                year = date.substring(5, 9);
            }
        } else {
            day = date.substring(0, 1);
            if (date.charAt(4) == "/") {
                month = date.substring(2, 4);
                year = date.substring(5, 9);
            } else {
                month = date.substring(2, 3);
                year = date.substring(4, 8);
            }
    }
    t.setDate(1);   
        t.setYear(year);
        t.setMonth(month - 1);
        t.setDate(day); 
        t = DateAdd("d", t, direction * 10);
        newMonth = t.getMonth() + 1;
        newDay = t.getDate();
        if (newDay < 10) { newDay = "0" + newDay; }
        if (newMonth < 10) { newMonth = "0" + newMonth; }
        newDate = newDay + "/" + newMonth + "/" + t.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById("_ctl1_currentDate").value = newDate;
    document.getElementById("aspnetForm").submit(); 
    }

    /* cette fonction fait un submit de la form globale TheForm, présente sur chaque page de portail */
    function redirectToQstWithDate(typeQST, OptMA, date) {

        var theForm = getTheForm();
        theForm.action = '' + document.getElementById("_ctl1_redirectUrl").value + '';
        if (OptMA && OptMA != "") {
          document.getElementById('OPTMA').value = OptMA;
        }
        document.getElementById('QST').value = typeQST;
        document.getElementById('ScreenSize').value = window.screen.width;
        document.getElementById('InputDate').value = date;

        __doPostBack('', '');
    }
</script>
```

This code worked for IE, where "jumpdate" (string) = The date I want to replace the default (current) date:

```
IE.document.getElementById("_ctl1_currentDate").Value = jumpDate
IE.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").submit
```

The attempt with the equivalent of the first line of the above code in Selenium Basic, which produces the SeleniumError "Element not interactable". "ch" is the Chrome driver reference:

```
 ch.FindElementById("_ctl1_currentDate").SendKeys (jumpDate)
```

I have the feeling that Selenium will not allow me to change the value of this element in Chrome. I think I need to fire the assocated Javascript; which is essentially what I was doing with the second line of the old IE code, whilst changing the argument with the first line of the old IE code.
I cannot get the syntax to do the equivalent of this in Selenium Basic with the .executeScript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation for selenium basic using `ExecuteScript` method to set the value attribute would be as follows, where you concatenate in the jumpDate value

```
.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('_ctl1_currentDate').setAttribute('value','" & jumpDate & "');"
```

Comment: Thank you @QHarr, this worked to change the value of the hidden input element with the rest of the code being fired by a similar submit statement to the original code: